# Proper foreign key structure with map tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I've got a Kanji database I'm putting together, and it's got several map tables to show one-to-many relationships between characters and how they can be read.

Keeping it simple, here are three sample tables:

```
`kanji`
    `id`
    `character`

`readings`
    `id`
    `reading`

`reading_map`
    `kanji` => Foreign Key to `kanji`.`id`
    `reading` => Foreign Key to `readings`.`id`
```

What I'm trying to figure out here is the proper way to set up the `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` settings for these two keys.

- I want the `reading_map` table's entry to be removed if a relevant entry is removed from either `kanji` or `readings`
- I don't want deleting an entry from `kanji` or `readings` to reach further to remove its companion entry—only the `reading_map` entry should be removed on delete, from either side
- I don't want `ON UPDATE` preventing me from updating other data on the linked tables (e.g. I want to be able to fix spelling errors in `readings`.`reading` without having to remove the entry from `reading_map` first).

I was thinking about setting `CASCADE` for `ON DELETE`, however since I'm linking the key from the map table I wasn't sure if that meant deleting the map entry would cascade outward, or if removing one of the linked entries would cascade inward.  I have no idea which is the right `ON UPDATE` setting.

Comment: Using "character" as a column name is a bad idea since it's a reserved word

Comment: @RhinoLarva, I don't agree with that. `name` is a reserved word too but it's probably one of the most common field names. Just be sure to use back ticks and you're fine. You should be using back ticks around all field names anyways, reserved or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on delete cascade` on the `reading_map` fields would delete `reading_map` records only when its corresponding key is deleted from the `readings` or `kanji` table. So your example is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks!  For the `ON UPDATE` settings, would I leave those at `NO ACTION/RESTRICT`?

Comment: Assuming your `kanji` and `readings` id's are auto increment then you can leave `on update` alone. The id's shouldn't ever change.

Comment: Gotcha, so it only cares about the ID fields, not anything else in those tables.  Thanks again!

Comment: It only cares about the id fields because that's what your foreign key references.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE readings_map (
  kanji INT NOT NULL,
  reading INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (kanji) REFERENCES kanji(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (reading) REFERENCES readings(id) ON DELETE CASCADE    
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97c1cc/1 - check the example here